# How do I copy the value of columns in one data frame to another data frame based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a data frame, say:

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe(rand(1,5)*0, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

and another data frame such as:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rand(1,3), columns = ['B','D','E'])
```

Is there a way to either add the values from df2 to df1, or replace the values from df1 with those of df2 based on column names? I am trying to do this within a loop and everything  iteration will return a different df2, with different values and columns (but the set of columns is always a subset of df1). df1 is all zeros and I want to fill the columns with the values I get from df2. My goal is to keep the same format so that my final df is the same length for every iteration with only the values from df2 replacing the zeros from df1 in the columns with matching names.

Comment: Is `df2` always 1-row?

Comment: Yes, df1 is 1 row by 11 columns and df2 is 1 row and the number of columns changes by iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
np.random.seed(2021)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5)*0, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,3), columns = ['B','D','E'])

print (df1)
     A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

print (df2)
          B         D         E
0  0.452145  0.201850  0.569305
1  0.195096  0.583704  0.476313

df1.update(df2)

print (df1)
     A         B    C         D         E
0  0.0  0.452145  0.0  0.201850  0.569305
1  0.0  0.195096  0.0  0.583704  0.476313
2  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000
3  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000
```